# Material Design: Анимация Transitions между активностями

Tags: android

Есть `GridView` с фотографиями. При нажатии на итем эта фотография должна перемещаться на вторую активность. Вот статья по которой я делал - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition. А вот желаемый эффект.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не получается. Нет анимации перехода. Я уже не знаю на что думать, поэтому вот весь код.

**gridview_item.xml**

```
<ru.albatros.material.ItemSquare
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid_iv"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:transitionName="photo"
    />

</ru.albatros.material.GridViewSquare>
```

**profile.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#cccccc"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

          <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_appbar_x"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                          android:id="@+id/mcollapsing"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                          app:contentScrim="#831296">

                          <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/grid_iv"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    android:transitionName="photo"
                                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

                          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

```
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fabrandom"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/main_appbar_x"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: А Вы на каком устройстве проверяете? В статье рецепт только для api 21 и выше

Comment: Знаю) Marshmallow у меня

Answer (score 2):

У меня работает такой вариант:

В стилях style.xml добавить

```
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

В нужном элементе в xxx_activity.xml:

```
android:transitionName="someNameTrans"
```

В обработчике onClick в Activity_XXX.java:

```
    Intent sharedActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedActivity.class);

    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[3];
    pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(prof_img, "someNameTrans");
    pairs[1] = new Pair<View, String>(prof_name, "someNameTrans1");
    pairs[2] = new Pair<View, String>(prof_descr, "someNameTrans2");

    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation (MainActivity.this, pairs);
    startActivity(sharedActivity, options.toBundle());
```